# Geometric description of set of points satisfying $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$

Tags: complex-numbers

How can we describe geometrically the set of points $z$ satisfying the condition $\mathrm{Im}(z)>0$ where $z$ is a complex number?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we write $z=x+yi$ with $x,y\in\mathbb R$ and draw this on the plane, we see that this is just the upper half plane, excluding the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: If $z=x+yi$, $x,y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\Im z>0$ then $y>0$ and $x\in \mathbb{R}$. What does this tell you?